# Sporadic HTTP 500 in Metadata GET : breeze metadata Could not find the CLR type for 'x' using DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, metadata, breeze

I know this will probably sound like a vague issue but I don't have a good handle yet on what is happening. Here's what I know:

I am using Breeze 1.4.2 with EF 5.

I have a sporadic issue while calling the Metadata HTTP Get for a specific controller. This controller is a POCO controller built using a code-first DbContext.

The only way I am able to get rid of this problem is by recycling IIs App pools on my 2 nodes load balanced environment. By the way, that only happens in Release mode on the target environment, I have never reproduced this bug locally.

Here's the MetaData method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public override string Metadata()
    {
        return new EFContextProvider<PersonalizationdDtoContext>().Metadata();
    }
```

Here's the context + configuration:

```
internal class PersonalizationdDtoContext : DbContext
{
    static PersonalizationdDtoContext()
    {
        // Prevent attempt to initialize a database for this context
        Database.SetInitializer<PersonalizationdDtoContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationDefaultsConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JsDataTableConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MobilePreferenceModelConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<MobilePreferenceModel> MobilePreferenceModel { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ApplicationDefaults> ApplicationDefaults { get; set; }

    public DbSet<JsDatatable> JsDatatables { get; set; }
}

internal class ApplicationDefaultsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationDefaults>
{
    public ApplicationDefaultsConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.LastUpdateDateTime).IsConcurrencyToken();
        this.Property(c => c.PreferenceTypeId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
    }
}

internal class JsDataTableConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<JsDatatable>
{
    public JsDataTableConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.LastUpdateDateTime).IsConcurrencyToken();
        this.Property(c => c.PreferenceTypeId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
        this.HasRequired(p => p.MobilePreferenceModel)
            .WithMany(p => p.JsDatatables)
            .HasForeignKey(q => q.MobilePreferenceModelID);
    }
}

internal class MobilePreferenceModelConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MobilePreferenceModel>
{
    public MobilePreferenceModelConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.HasOptional(p => p.ApplicationDefaults)
            .WithRequired();
    }
}
```

I am going to try to upgrade to latest breeze assemblies on the server to see if I can get passed this issue.

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: I think this was a load balancer issue. One of the IIs node had a capital letter in. I'll report back if this is the problem

Comment: We found out that connectionstring is important on the context, even if it never connects anywhere. This is important at construction time and if you do not specify any connectionstring in  the class constructor it is going to try to read the connectionstring from the web.config. In my case, Creating a connectionstring named PersonalizationdDtoContext seems to have helped with this issue.